# How can I alter the spacing for the Y-Axis Labels in MPAndroidchart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

How can I make my YAxis labels elevated with a gap i.e., start from a given value like the below picture? If I try using offset it makes my YAxis label values plot incorrectly against the Y-Axis data.

[image: a stock price line chart with the YAxis labels starting from $412.66]

Here is my code so far:

```
  public void setChartProperties() {
        YAxis rightAxis = chart.getAxisRight();
        YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
        XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
        chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
        chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        chart.setDrawBorders(false);
        chart.setPinchZoom(false);
        chart.setAutoScaleMinMaxEnabled(true);
        chart.setExtraOffsets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        xAxis.setLabelCount(6, true);
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
        leftAxis.setPosition(YAxisLabelPosition.INSIDE_CHART);
        leftAxis.setDrawLabels(true);
        leftAxis.setSpaceBottom(60);
        leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
        leftAxis.setLabelCount(3, true);
        leftAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
        leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        rightAxis.setEnabled(false);
        xAxis.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
        dataSet.setColor(R.color.graphLineColor);
    }
```

And here is a screenshot of what my chart looks like.

[image: a chart with the YAxis labels starting from the correct value but with incorrect yValues]

Comment: Have any code so far?

Comment: Added code above. Thanks!

Comment: You mean you just want the labels to show for yValues above a certain level? So not show all of the labels, right?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Above and below, I want to replicate the blue picture above. I used leftAxis.setSpaceBottom(60); to have my YAxis data start 60f from the bottom, but I have yet to replicate 3 labels like above. I've also tried leftAxis.setLabelCount(3, true);, but the library decides the spacing and value of the labels ( like my picture above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was achieved through implementing `IAxisValueFormatter` because I wanted to keep all values and just modify the labels:

```
public class MyValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {

    private final float cutoff;
    private final DecimalFormat format;

    public MyValueFormatter(float cutoff) {
        this.cutoff = cutoff;
        this.format = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,##0.00");
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        if (value < cutoff) {
            return "";
        }

        return "$" + format.format(value);
    }
}
```

And then I consume it using:

```
leftAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter(yMin));
```

where `yMin` was defined earlier:

```
private float yMin = 0;
```

and then assigned the chart's minimum yValue was passed in.

[image: a chart with the YAxis labels starting from the minimum yValue as per OP's requirement]