# How to change position of y-axis label using mpandroidchart library?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I've searched the wiki, SO, the issues section of https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues, but have been unable to find an answer to my question.

I simply want to change the position of the y-axis values above the horizontal grid lines. I can move them into the graph with leftAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.INSIDE_CHART), but there doesn't seem to be any way to move their position vertically.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:[yaxis_label_above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oizOb.png)

Here is what it currently looks like:
[yaxis_label_on_line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTf4g.png)

Is it possible to move the position of the y-axis labels vertically either up or down?

Answer (score 2):

`The AxisValueFormatter interface` ([Link](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-AxisValueFormatter-interface))

More details please refer to [How can I alter the spacing for the Y-Axis Labels in MPAndroidchart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468599/how-can-i-alter-the-spacing-for-the-y-axis-labels-in-mpandroidchart)